# PostGIS geography query returns a string value

Tags: postgis

I have a strange issue. The lonlat column on my app works well on the development server –– its output is in the form of POINT(X Y). But when I move the data to the production server, the output is strange!

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `lon' for "0101000020E6100000541B9C887E7A52C02920ED7F80614440":String):

The lonlat value, which is encoded with SRID: 4326, is being read as a string. I am almost certain that there was a corruption in the data during migrating it from development to production because this was not a problem before the migration.

Does anyone know what about the database schema or column may cause this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What language are you using for your application and What versions of PostgreSQL / PostGIS are you running?  I'm guessing the issue is with your application tier and not the database and your application tier perhaps doesn't know how to cast what it's getting back (doesn't recognize it as a geometry.  The string rep you have is the canonical form of a PostGIS geometry you see if PostGIS is cast to text.  To demonstrate try this in your database and it should return POINT(-73.913973 40.761734)

```
SELECT ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000541B9C887E7A52C02920ED7F80614440'::geometry);
```

If you upgraded your postgresqL from say 8.4 to 9.0 the output of things changed so things got output as hex (which instead of escape).  If you are suffering from this particular issue, read the FAQ on this topic:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/PostGIS_FAQ.html#legacy_faq_read_view

Another possibility is 2.0/1.5 in 2.0, we have typmod, and if you have some sort of ORM thing, you might be using a 1.5 version of it and it doesn't know what this extra info is.  Might need to upgrade your PostGIS plugin on your app.

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right path. It was the application tier. Turns out that when I killed the connection to the server to migrate the data, Rails did not set the schema search path (meaning didn't discover the postgis extension) upon reconnecting. I had to restart the server to solve this problem.